# Are there international laws that compel Mexico to prevent migrants from crossing the border and into the U.S.?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, refugees

Are there international laws that compel Mexico to prevent migrants from crossing the border and into the U.S.? I am asking, because I am wondering if there's any legitimate grievance from the U.S., because from my understanding all they are required to do is not let people enter illegally under their noses at a border checkpoint, but they can't be legally required to not let anyone cross the border.

Also, I am wondering about cases where you have caravans carrying people who seek to escape poverty. Is there any law that tells you how a country must handle those situations?

Comment: International law is "whatever one gets away with in practice." USA is powerful enough to rewrite those laws.

Comment: @Sjoerd - You're not wrong. I'd extend that even to domestic laws.

Comment: Isn't the issue having Mexico stop Country X citizens from crossing the X-Mexico border?

Comment: "from my understanding all they are required to do is not let people enter illegally under their noses at a border checkpoint": enter where illegally, Mexico or the US?  Either way, I know of no relevant international law, but I highly doubt that there is anything compelling a country not to let certain people *in.*  There might be something that requires some countries to regulate outbound traffic to a neighboring country, but I suspect that if there is, it is effected through bilateral agreements, and I highly doubt that Mexico and the US have concluded such an agreement.